# Get linebreaks at a long list

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, line

How can I get linebreaks at a very long list like `1,2,3,...`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\let\mylist=\empty
\foreach \k in {1,...,44}{
  \ifx\empty\mylist{} \xdef\mylist{\k}%
  \else \xdef\mylist{\mylist,\,\k}%
  \fi
}

\section{Overlapping}
mylist: \mylist

parbox: \parbox{0.8\linewidth}{\mylist}

minipage: \begin{minipage}{5cm}  \mylist  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using `~` in `\xdef\mylist{\mylist,~\k}` and thus get unbreakable spaces between the entries. You could look into using `\xdef\mylist{\mylist, \k}`

Comment: Now as you say that.... :) I had sometimes the problem, that this way of listmaking does not work, if I put in a 'space'. But here not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there are better answers. I realized it is the same that moewe  provided before. Please do not vote.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \let\mylist=\empty
    \foreach \k in {1,...,44}{
        \ifx\empty\mylist{} \xdef\mylist{\k,}% <<<<<
        \else   
        \xdef\mylist{\mylist\, \k,}% <<<<   
        \fi
    }
    
    \section{Overlapping}
    mylist: \mylist
    
    parbox: \parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\mylist}
    
    minipage: \begin{minipage}{3cm}  \mylist  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]